# How to count the number of columns with specific data in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, reportviewer

I have a temp table as shown in following screen shot. I populate this table using an SP as an intermediate step to generate a report.

[image]

This table contains Employee ID, PID (working location) and days from 1st to 31st. If an employee has worked a Day Shift its denoted by `D` and night shifts are denoted by `N`. If an employee has worked both shifts its denoted by `D/N`. Now I have to get the totals to last columns as follows.

- `sub_totals` - total of "D" and "N" separately. ex. "15/08"
- `shift_totals` - total of shifts together. ex. "23" (All "D"s and "N"s)
- `day_totals` - number of days worked (count of D, N and D/N) ex. "20"

**NOT:** When calculating `day-total`, "D/N" should be treated as a one day worked.

Finally I want to show this on a report. (development language is C# and I'm using ADO.NET)

Could someone please show me how to do this in SQL if possible?

Comment: One thing that is going to be hard to do in SQL is to fire whoever designed that table.

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen, actually its a temp table build by an SP as an intermediate step to ease the generation of report ;)

Comment: So the underlying data is not formatted like that?

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen, Data is formatted by the SP. The screen shot shows the real table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    PID,
    (
        CASE WHEN [1] = 'D' OR [1] = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE IF [1] = 'D/N' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN [2] = ...
      + ...
      + CASE WHEN [31] = 'D' OR [31] = 'N' .....
    ) AS shift_totals,
    (
        CASE WHEN [1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN [2] IS ...
      + ...
    ) AS day_totals
```